# Why i am not able to open my archieved chats?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My archieved whatsApp messages not opening at all. I am not able to click it and open it(convert)

Comment: Sorry I'm failing to understand... Did you export the chats out of WhatsApp?. Because the only option in WhatsApp to archive chat can be found by scrolling to the bottom of the screen and going into the chats hidden. Please clarify which archive method you used so I can help you further

Answer (score 1):

To open WhatsApp archived/exported chat, you need an app that is able to open .txt file, because WhatsApp archived/exported chat has that format. You can use this [text viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.panagola.app.textviewer&hl=en) app from the Play Store.